# Run a program during actual boot time on Windows

Tags: windows, boot, services

For the reference, there are bunch of irrelevant question when you try to search for generic words `windows run app during boot` but few dozens I went through are all incorrect since they target the cases when things needs to be ran at startup.

Mine inst.

I need to run some basic operations/program during Windows boot time BEFORE most of the services started. Ideally - before `RPCSS` (Remote Procedure Call) starts. Testing few different methods shows that this service up and running as early as it gets. So I somehow need to be able to run an executable earlier than that or at least on par.

I probably could make a fake service, screw around with `OrderGroups` and `ServiceGroupOrder`, make the service start practically the first and then successfully make it stop/quit after doing the operation but this seems absolute overkill for a simple file copy operation. I also cannot really on any 3rd party solution, this is something that should be doable on stock Windows.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Why are you trying to mess with files so early in the startup sequence? Why can't you do it later?

Comment: There is no error or confusion in my formulation, I know what I need and I know it can't be done any other way due to dependence on services state. Further meta discussion would be irrelevant.

Comment: Well you could write a batch file that stop the services blocking your file operation, do the file operation and then restart the stopped services. Stick that batch file in your startup folder.

Comment: You cant control RPCSS at all. And stopping other services is dangerously unreliable, depending on the situation they might refuse or get stuck in forever shutdown, especially if there is some pending update operations at the start time- trying to do anything during this state with system might result in softlock/loop. You are assuming what I need when I've already investigated it and came to inevitable conclusion and written my question in plain text.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible on a stock windows install. That's why people mess around with rootkits to bypass OS security.

Comment: I always can fall back to custom service installation, just dont want to. Hopefully someone else can drop by later and give some insight.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're trying to do but before getting into boot drivers, what about using the Session Manager's Pending File Rename Operations (PFRO) feature?  MoveFileExA is the API but you can just update the registry value manually to use MoveFIle from Sysinternals. Is that early enough?

Comment: Have you thought of doing it the other way around, i.e. by delaying RPC on startup, so that the program you want to start before that has the time to launch. You can even set RPC to manual if you must. Other than that, you'll have to resort to writing your own program, in the same vein as what Avast or Defraggler do when they launch on the very early onset of Windows boot.